# How to Pivot the data Based on another column value

Tags: pandas, hive, pyspark, pivot, impala

I am trying to Pivot/Transpose my column values and trying get  corresponding datetime .

table i have:

```
User  Status     LogTime
----------------------------------------
Tom   Active     2019-09-06 17:36:08.233
Tom   Active     2019-09-06 18:37:08.244
Tom   Active     2019-09-06 20:46:08.133
Tom   InActive   2019-09-06 23:46:08.133
Tom   Active     2019-09-07 12:37:08.244
Tom   Active     2019-09-08 10:46:08.133
Tom   InActive   2019-09-08 11:46:08.133
```

Trying to get the data like below.

```
User  Active                     InActive
------------------------------------------------------
Tom  2019-09-06 20:46:08.133   2019-09-06 23:46:08.133
Tom  2019-09-08 10:46:08.133   2019-09-08 11:46:08.133
```

I'm trying to transpose the Status column with last active logtime and inactive logtime after the last active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query works in Hive with your dataset. 
I tried to take into account possible boundary conditions when it is no InActive or Active status in the log for the user, of course the logic should be verified and adjusted on real dataset.

Demo:

```
with data as (
select stack(7,
'Tom','Active',   '2019-09-06 17:36:08.233',
'Tom','Active',   '2019-09-06 18:37:08.244',
'Tom','Active',   '2019-09-06 20:46:08.133',
'Tom','InActive', '2019-09-06 23:46:08.133',
'Tom','Active',   '2019-09-07 12:37:08.244',
'Tom','Active',   '2019-09-08 10:46:08.133',
'Tom','InActive', '2019-09-08 11:46:08.133'
) as(User,Status,LogTime)
) --use your_table instead of this


select User, Active, InActive
from
(
select User,MaxInActive,MaxActive,--Status,LogTime,nextStatus,
       case when (prevStatus='Active' and Status='InActive')  --the last Active LogTime
                 then prevLogTime
            when (Status='Active' and nextStatus is NULL) --boundary condition, Active is the last status, take current
                 OR (LogTime=MaxActive  and MaxInActive is NULL) --No InActive, take current
                 then LogTime             
       end as Active,

       case when (prevStatus='Active' and Status='InActive') --InActive LogTime after the last Active
                 OR (LogTime=MaxInActive and MaxActive is NULL) --No Active exists, take current
                 then LogTime
       end as InActive

from       
(
select User,Status,LogTime,
       max(case when Status='InActive' then LogTime end) over(partition by User) as MaxInActive ,
       max(case when Status='Active' then LogTime end) over(partition by User) as MaxActive,
       lead(Status) over(partition by User order by LogTime) nextStatus,
       lag(Status) over(partition by User order by LogTime) prevStatus,
       lag(LogTime) over(partition by User order by LogTime) prevLogTime
  from data
)s
)s
where (Active is not NULL and InActive is not NULL)
      or (MaxInActive is NULL and Active is not NULL) --only active records exist
      or (MaxActive is NULL and MaxInActive is not NULL) --only inactive exists
 ;
```

Result:

```
OK
user    active  inactive
Tom     2019-09-06 20:46:08.133 2019-09-06 23:46:08.133
Tom     2019-09-08 10:46:08.133 2019-09-08 11:46:08.133
Time taken: 100.645 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Comment: Working perfectly...Thanks alot @leftjoin

Comment: @Rahul You are wellcome

Comment: @leftjoin.. It's nice to sort out " boundary conditions when it is no InActive or Active status in the log for the user"

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to grab the previous row of `InActive` , then segregate every 2 rows as a group and [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
m=df[df.Status.eq('InActive')|df.Status.eq('InActive').shift(-1)].reset_index(drop=True)
m.assign(k=m.groupby(m.index//2).ngroup()).set_index(['User','Status','k']).unstack(1)
```

---

```
                        LogTime                         
Status                   Active                 InActive
User k                                                  
Tom  0  2019-09-06 20:46:08.133  2019-09-06 23:46:08.133
     1  2019-09-08 10:46:08.133  2019-09-08 11:46:08.133
```

Or using the same `m` with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
m.assign(k=m.groupby(m.index//2).ngroup()).pivot_table(index=['User','k']
          ,columns='Status',values='LogTime',aggfunc='first').rename_axis(None,axis=1)
```

---

```
                      Active                 InActive
User k                                                  
Tom  0  2019-09-06 20:46:08.133  2019-09-06 23:46:08.133
     1  2019-09-08 10:46:08.133  2019-09-08 11:46:08.133
```

Answer (score 0):

Try groupby on 'User', 'Status', 'date' part of 'LogTime' and call 'last' on 'LogTime'. Next, 'unstack', put index to columns and drop undesired columns and 'dropna'

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['User','Status', df.LogTime.dt.date]).LogTime.last()
        .unstack(1).reset_index().drop('LogTime',1).dropna())

Out[890]:
Status User                  Active                InActive
0       Tom 2019-09-06 20:46:08.133 2019-09-06 23:46:08.133
2       Tom 2019-09-08 10:46:08.133 2019-09-08 11:46:08.133
```